# PhpMyAdmin: как задать значение всем строкам в столбце?

Tags: phpmyadmin, интерфейс, выборка

Как бы вы массово присвоили значение всем строкам столбца в выборке, в phpMyAdmin? В таблице есть столбец `empty` и строки со значениями 1 и 0. Хотелось бы задать всем строкам со значением 1 значение 0.

Comment: > в выборке, в pma  
> строкам со значением 1, значение 0

запятые не нужны

следующий запрос проставит значение 0 в поле empty для всех записей, 
у которых значение `string_column` равняется единице. Названия таблицы `tbl` и строкового поля `string_column` надо заменить на свои, конечно.

    UPDATE tbl SET empty = 0 WHERE string_column = '1'

Comment: т.е. только запросом? Спасибо.

Comment: @Alex Lapin, честно не знаю, запросом привычнее

Comment: @Fike, вот так чуток правильнее 

UPDATE tbl SET empty = 0 WHERE empty = '1'

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Проще всего выполнить эту задачу SQL-запросом `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE
  tbl
SET
  empty = 0
WHERE
  empty = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Update tbl set empty=0 where 1